# Jquery timer with UTC offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function getMinutesUntilNextHour() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getUTCHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var secs = now.getSeconds();

    // Compute time remaining per unit
    var cur_hours = 23 - hours;
    var cur_mins = 60 - mins;
    var cur_secs = 60 - secs;

    // Correct zero padding of hours if needed
    if (cur_hours < 10) {
        cur_hours = '0' + cur_hours;
    }
    // Correct zero padding of minutes if needed
    if (cur_mins < 10) {
        cur_mins = '0' + cur_mins;
```

Here’s the code for a simple 24 hour countdown timer that resets again after each 24 hours but when I add, say, 11- hours in the compute time remaining section it occasionally throws a negative time (in hours) at me depending on the current UTC time. I’d just like the 24 hour period to start from a different time /time zone. All help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking at this backwards :-) Why don't you create a Date object for midnight, then subtract current time from it. This example works for the local timezone, but you could easily adapt it for UTC, or another timezone.

```js
// We're going to use Vue to update the page each time our counter changes.
// You could also do this old style, updating the DOM directly.
// vueStore is just a global variable that will contain the current time, 
// and the function to periodically update it.
var vueStore = { 
now: new Date(),
  countdown(){
    vueStore.now = new Date();
    window.setTimeout(() => {this.countdown(); }, 1000);
  }
};
vueStore.countdown();


var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#vueRoot",
    data: { vueStore: vueStore },
    computed: {
        timeTilMidnight() {
            var midnightTonight = new Date(this.vueStore.now.getYear(), this.vueStore.now.getMonth(), this.vueStore.now.getDay() + 1);
            var timeToMidnight = midnightTonight.getTime() - this.vueStore.now.getTime();

            return new Date(timeToMidnight).toLocaleTimeString([], {
                timeZone: "UTC"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vueRoot">
<h1>{{timeTilMidnight}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What is vueStore? And are there any cons to using that over the bog standard script source?

Comment: Sorry ! Vue has nothing to do with your question. The whole answer to your question is in the function `timeTilMidnight()`. All the rest is boilerplate. It lets the goodness flow out onto the page without using `getElementById()`. Of course I think it's very good boilerplate, but you're in no way obliged to use it.